# Paypal pro Recurring billing gets suspended in sandbox

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using angelleye PayPal library for creating recurring profile in CodeIgniter.

Profile gets successfully created and I am getting profile id.

I have kept billing period each day. But the auto-bill for the same profile get suspended.

I get sandbox notification with this heading :

"An automatic payment from testperson new failed"
and inside its subject this is written "The automatic payment from testperson new has failed".

So what could be the reason. I have used dummy credit card details on creating recurring profile.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a callback script to validate the payments etc? If I recall correctly, if you do not respond correctly to this, it will fail. Common issue is due to an error?

Comment: No, I am not using any such script. When I call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile method I am getting profile ID. After that I am checking the sandbox and I am getting the notification that "You have a new automatic payment profile for testperson" and after few minutes Because for test reason I have given billingperiod='Day' and billingfrequency='1' I am getting first notification which says  "Automatic payments from testperson were suspended" and then another notification which says:"An automatic payment from testperson failed". So I am not getting what is going wrong.

Comment: I have used dummy credit card details. Even in the notification it is written   "We've sent your customer an email asking them to make sure their payment information is correct." But I never got any such mail.

Comment: This sounds like the test card information is invalid? Are you simply setting up a recurring payment, or are you taking an initial payment too? Could be worth trying to take a payment using the same details and see if that fails?

Comment: Hey Gavin, before creating recurring profile I checked the card details with DoDirectPayment and it is working. And I am not setting any  initial payment.